# Where is my shiny server

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, windows-subsystem-for-linux, r

1. I am new to linux.
2. I try to deploy a shiny server locally on my windows machine with ubuntu WSL.
3. I successfully installed ubuntu WSL on my windows machine and I can start ubuntu.

- **I come here so far:**

`tarjae@DESKTOP-LNI8ONS:~$`

- If I type `dir` I get this:

```
R       rstudio-server-latest-amd64.deb    shiny-server-1.5.17.973-amd64.deb.1
app1.R  shiny-server-1.5.17.973-amd64.deb
```

From now on everything that happens is random for me, depending on which tutorial I go through!

**So my question is:**

1. How can I check whether I am the root or a user? (Source for basic managing linux commands)?
2. Where is my shiny server?
3. How can I start the server `sudo start shiny-server` does not work ->

```
tarjae@DESKTOP-LNI8ONS:~$ sudo start shiny-server
[sudo] password for tarjae:
sudo: start: command not found
```

4. And finally how can I start `app1.R`

I am fully aware that all this is kind of wage. But I hope to get the next step for my purposes. ANY directing advice is highly appreciated.

**Update1:**

`dpkg-query -l shiny` shows

`dpkg-query: no packages found matching shiny`

- After `sudo apt install ./shiny-server-1.5.17.973-amd64.deb` it shows:

```
Note, selecting 'shiny-server' instead of './shiny-server-1.5.17.973-amd64.deb'
shiny-server is already the newest version (1.5.17.973).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
```

**Update 2:**

With

```
tarjae@DESKTOP-LNI8ONS:~$ dpkg-query -l | grep shiny
```

I get:

```
ii  shiny-server                   1.5.17.973                            amd64        Shiny Server
```

- Then with

```
tarjae@DESKTOP-LNI8ONS:~$ systemctl start shiny-server
```

I get:

```
tarjae@DESKTOP-LNI8ONS:~$ systemctl start shiny-server
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

**Update 3:**

```
tarjae@DESKTOP-LNI8ONS:/home/shiny$ sudo service shiny-server start
```

I get:

```
tarjae@DESKTOP-LNI8ONS:/home/shiny$
```

Nothing happens. Last days I read a blog where I should create a new user and I did and with this new user I could see something on localhost:3838. I am sorry to take your time!

If I do:

```
tarjae@DESKTOP-LNI8ONS:~$ service shiny-server status
#OR
tarjae@DESKTOP-LNI8ONS:~$ sudo service shiny-server status
# I get:
tarjae@DESKTOP-LNI8ONS:~$
```

Comment: Well, do you see the Shiny Server home page at the URL? If so, then it's working.

Comment: Unfortunately not! Anyway many thanks for your time. I think with my windows brain I am not able to cover this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to hear you have it working on a droplet.  I gave it a shot myself on WSL2/Ubuntu, and there are definitely a few issues.

Honestly, you've done very well in parsing out the competing directions given how new you are to Linux.  You've tried exactly the right things in exactly the right order.  I can explain here *why* they didn't work, and, hopefully, how to get it running.

###### For your "Update2":

```
systemctl start shiny-server
```

Yes, this is the "normal" method of starting it, but `systemctl` requires Systemd, which doesn't work on WSL2 without some hacky workarounds.  Systemd is the init mechanism for most Linux distributions nowadays, but WSL needs its own `/init` in order to setup its tight integration with Windows (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328686/1165986) for more details on `/init` and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986) for more info on Systemd under WSL2).

###### For your "Update3":

```
sudo start shiny-server
```

And again, you are absolutely right.  Many applications and distributions still provide "older-style" init scripts for the SysVInit system that predated Systemd.  Those scripts *will* typically run on WSL2 (and even WSL1) using the `service` command.

However, often these init scripts have been unmaintained or untested for too long.  In this case, there's a definite bug in the init script that is causing it to fail.  This bug would even prevent it from running on a "normal" (non-WSL) Ubuntu.

Two lines in the script cause it to fail before it even gets started:

```
DAEMON=shiny-server
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0
```

This basically says, "Does the file 'shiny-server' exist with executable permissions?  If not, exit the script."

Unfortunately, it doesn't provide the *path* to `shiny-server`.  Changing the first line to ...

```
DAEMON=/opt/shiny-server/bin/shiny-server
```

... allows it to work, at least for `service shiny-server start`:

```
$ pgrep -x shiny-server
$ sudo service shiny-server start
$ pgrep -x shiny-server
7184
```

That said, there appear to be even more issues beyond that one, so restarting the service will also fail, and there's no support for `status` either.

Note that both `service` and `systemctl` are "convenience" methods of a sort.  It's entirely possible to handle this on your own, especially for "simple" servers like `shiny`.

You can either look at the `/etc/init.d/shiny-server` or `/opt/shiny-server/config/systemd/shiny-server.service` to see what those files are doing, although this will admittedly be easier as you gain Linux experience.

That at least has it running, although I haven't actually tried it out to know if the functionality in there works at that point.  If you do run into additional problems, though, I feel confident we can sort them out on WSL2.  It's "just" a matter of knowing where to look.

Comment: This is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, it seems that you can open tcp ports on WSL. So the issue must be on systemd. Apparently it's not used by WSL as init. Perhaps you could start shiny-server manually.

Comment: I will try this out. Thank you very much. Now I have changed my strategy. I have decided to host both shinyserver and rstudio server on digital ocean. And I was successful. I learned a lot in the past few days. Later with more knowledge I will start a shinyserver on my machine.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, I changed the answer so that it wouldn't mislead others. Thank you for pointing out.